# Linear algebra. Proof of linear independence.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let functions $f_1(x)=|x-1|$, $f_2(x)=|x-2|$, $f_3(x)=|x-3|$ be elements of the linear space $F(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$ of all functions of $\mathbb R$ in $\mathbb R$. Prove that the system $f_1$, $f_2$, $f_3$ is linearly independent.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP showed no effort to solve the problem and\or didn't addressed his/her difficulties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prove that 
$a_1 f_1 + a_2 f_2 +a_3 f_3 =0$ implies $a_1=a_2=a_3=0$.

Note that $a_1 f_1 + a_2 f_2 +a_3 f_3 =0$ means $a_1 f_1(x) + a_2 f_2(x) +a_3 f_3(x) =0$ for all $x$.

*Hint:* evaluate at $x=1,2,3$.

Comment: Ok, I have
a2 + 2a3 = 0 for x = 1;
a1 + a3 = 0 for x = 2;
2a1 + a2 = 0 for x = 3;
but I don't know what's next

Comment: Yes, but is it enough to check what happens for x = 1, x = 2 and x = 3? What happens to other values of x?

Comment: @user119806, $a_1,a_2,a_3$ do not depend on $x$. They determine a linear combinations of *functions*, not of *values*.